# getting confusion on this explain this loop result in java

Tags: java

```
int a = 0, b = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (++a > 2 || ++b > 2) {
        a++;
    }
}

System.out.println("a= " + a + " b=" + b);
```

can you explain the logic please?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `++a` and `a++`? If so, what is your logic problem?

Comment: what is the output your getting and what did you expect ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to read and understand what a pre-increment and post-increment operator does, then do a dry run of this program manually on a sheet, then tally the result with PC o/p. That would clear your concepts. Practice is the key!

Comment: The best way to understand something like this is to step through it with a debugger, checking the values of all the variables after each step.

Comment: To "clear a concept" is very non-idiomatic English.  You can clear a cheque, or a blocked drain, or a bar (in high jumping), but concepts are *understood* ... not cleared.  (Can someone enlighten me as to where this "clear a concept" usage comes from?)

Comment: `++a` this will increment `a` by 1 one and check `> 2`. If it is `a++` -this will check for condition first then increment by one.

Comment: @StephenC My apologies for the mistake! English isn't my native language. Thanks! I need not refer this now https://english.stackexchange.com/ as people here also correct grammatical or (human spoken)language mistakes. :-)

Comment: @coolgirl - I'm curious.  What is your native language?  And where did you learn this "clear a concept" phraseology?  (Is it coming from some language translation software?)

Answer (score 0):

i=0 a=1 (1st condition is false so 2nd is check) b=1

i=1 a=2 (1st condition is false so 2nd is check) b=2

i=2 ++a increment a , a=3 condition is true enter in if condition and a become 4 and b remain 2

similarly i=3 a=6 b=2 and i=4 a=8 b=2;

In case of or(||) condition whenever compiler encounter true condition it stop checking other statement

Answer (score 0):

These are the five iteration and result of a & b finally. Every row is the result of every single iteration in loop.

```
a     b
--------
1     1
2     2
4     2
6     2
8     2

++a > 2    means   increment a (by 1) first than compare with 2
++b > 2    means   increment b (by 1) first than compare with 2
a++        means   a=a+1;  means increment a by 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion may come from `++a` vs `a++`. So basicly, both of them increment the value carried by `a` by `1`, this mean `a = a + 1`.

The difference is `++a` will do the increment first, then do the comparison, while `a++` will do the comparison first then increment.

So look at your code:

- 1st line: just declaring variables `a` and `b`, and instantiating
- 3rd line: `for` loop will iterate 5 times

First iteration:
- 4th line: `++a` ---> `a == 1`, then compare it to `2`, so on for `b`, here the expression returns `false`, so skip line 5.

- 9th line: here it prints out `a= 1 b=1`

Second iteration:
- 4th line: `++a` ---> `a == 2`, then compare it to `2`, so on for `b`, here the expression returns `false`, so skip line 5.

- 9th line: here it prints out `a= 2 b=2`

Third iteration: (later iterations are similar)
- 4th line: `++a` ---> `a == 3`, then compare it to `2`, so on for `b`, here the expression returns `true`, so line 5 is reached now.

- 5th line: `a++` ---> `a == 4`
- 9th line: here it prints out `a= 4 b=3`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

++a means the current value of a is increased by 1 before the operations.(in this case, it increase value of a by 1 before compare a > 2)
a++ means the current value of a is increased by 1 after the operations. (in this case, increase value of a, although there is no operations.)

For loop is not interrupted by anything..... So, it loops for 5 times(i = 0,1,2,3,4).

for i = 0 -> 
current value of a = 0, current value of b = 0

> if ( ++a > 2 || ++b > 2 )

in this statement, a is increase by 1 before compare with 2. So the current value is 0 and the increased by 1. new value is 1.
now compare a (1) with 2.... and same thing happens with the b.

> if ( 1 > 2 || 1 > 2 )

the statement is false. so go to the end of the end statement.

for i = 1 -> current value of a = 1, current value of b = 1

same as before value of a is increased by 1 before compare 'a > 2' and also with the b.( new a = 2, b = 2 )

> if (2 > 2 || 2 > 2 )

statement is false. to the end of the if statement.

for i = 2 -> current value of a = 2, b = 2

increase a by 1 -> a = 3 and also b = 3 before compare.

> if ( 3 > 2 || 3 > 2 )

if condition becomes true. then

> a++

statement executes.
new value of a = 4. value of b stays the same (3).

for i =3 -> current values a = 4, b = 3
increase a and b by 1 new values (a= 4, b =4 )

> if ( 5 > 2 || 4 > 2 )

true. then

> a++

new value of a = 6, b stays the same (4).

for i = 4 -> current values a = 6, b = 4.
increase a and b ( 7, 5 )

> if ( 7 > 2 || 5 > 2 )

true. then

> a++

new value of a = 8. and b stays the same (5).

end of the for loop ( i < 5 condition fails)

next statement

> System.out.println("a= " + a + " b=" + b)

displays "a= 8 b=5"